# Cannot create plot using pandas.dataframe.hist()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value1': [1, 5, 9], 'value2': [56, 84, 98]})
df.hist()
```

but no plot popped up, the program just ran and stopped.
I'm sure I have all the required packages, and I can plot with matplotlib like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value1': [1, 5, 9], 'value2': [56, 84, 98]})
plt.scatter(df['value1'], df['value2'])
plt.show()
```

I'm using windows 10 pro, python 3.6.4.

Comment: Where are you running the code ?

Comment: It work fine on my side

Comment: Do you call `plt.show()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `plt.show()` if you run your script from command line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value1': [1, 5, 9], 'value2': [56, 84, 98]})
df.hist()
plt.show()
```

If you are in a Jupyter notebook, you need turn on a suitable backend such as:

```
%matplotlib inline
```